# How to get the mailer method after a message is sent in ActionMailer 3.2.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm try to log all emails sent out by our system. I've setup a callback in ActionMailer::Base using this blog for reference: http://www.javier-julio.com/2013/03/29/using-callbacks-in-rails-3-actionmailer.

I'm trying to save a record that logs the actionmailer object used and the method called after the message is delivered. I have access the `mail` and `message`objects.

```
include AbstractController::Callbacks

after_filter :log_email

def log_email
  klass = ActiveSupport::Inflector.underscore(self.class.name)
  SystemEmail.create(user: User.find_by_email(message.to), key: "#{klass}.#{message.template_name}" )
end
```

template_name however is not exposed as of Rails3 and I haven't been able to find a way to access the mailer method that is being called. How can I find the mailer action that has been called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `action_name`, so your method will be:

```
def log_email
  klass = ActiveSupport::Inflector.underscore(self.class.name)
  SystemEmail.create(user: User.find_by_email(message.to), key: "#{klass}.#{action_name}" )
end
```